# Get original association between levels and labels in factor variables

Tags: r, label, factors, levels

I'm looking for a function to get the original mapping table of factor variable. I import an Rdata file. I've got a factor variable named "FactVar". I know the mapping table for "FactVar" is as follows:

```
"010025" -> city1
"015146" -> city2
"048017" -> city3
"082053" -> city4
```

In my dataframe the "FactVar" data are as follows (first 5 cases):

```
1: city1
2: city3
3: city4
4: city1
5: city3
```

So, no "city2" in my df. Which function can I use to get the original mapping table? is it available in my Rdata file?

Thank you

EDIT:
I try to clarify my question with a better example. I have a survey question with the following possible answers:

```
1: "Yes"
2: "No"
8: "Don't Know"
9: "Not Applicable"
```

I create a factor variable "FactVar":

```
Var <- c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,8,1,2)
FactVar <- factor(Var, levels=c(1,2,8,9), labels=c("Yes", "No", "Don't Know", "Not Applicable")
```

As you see, in my Rdata file I've got a factor variable where no data are linked to the level "Not Applicable". How can I get the original mapping table as in my survey question?

Comment: What results does `levels(FactVar[[1]])` give you?

Comment: I got only the labels, like "city1", "city2", etc.

Comment: can you dput your input? What the name of your dataframe? you say you have a factor but apparently you defined 4 variable containing strings? sorry it's not clear at all!

Comment: @Scido Apologies, I meant `as.numeric` instead of `levels`. I got confused because your factors look like strings rather than numeric variables — what’s going on there?

Answer (score 3):

The answer, I think, is "no." I don't have any explicit information to back this up, but even poring over the documentation for `factor` and related functions I don't see any way to recover the original levels, unless you store them separately (e.g. as an `attribute`, or saving the original function call) when the factor is created.

Frankly I think this is somewhat of an oversight in the design of the program, and while it's definitely somewhat of an edge case (I've never thought about it before), I'm going to put a bounty on this question and hope that it gets the attention of Dirk Eddelbuettel or one of the other R gurus.

Edit: I don't see the "add bounty" button. Maybe it'll show up in a few days (and hopefully I remember).

Comment: I'm interested in the answer as well. It seems that, for example, if you want to turn a variable into a labelled factor AND keep the original data, you have to create a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had this question before, which was answered here: [How to access actual internal factor lookup hashtable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247041/how-to-access-actual-internal-factor-lookup-hashtable-in-r)

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to put this in comments.

Comment: Sorry @Allen, but it doesn't resolve my question. I tried with my example: `.levels <- levels(FactVar)`, `h <- hash(keys = .levels,values = seq_along(.levels))` and the result is:`<hash> containing 4 key-value pair(s).
  Don't Know : 3
  No : 2
  Not Applicable : 4
  Yes : 1`
I think @ssdecontrol is right, so far there's no way the get the original mapping table...

Answer (score 0):

```
str(FactVar)
```

will give you back the mapping between the levels and their labels like this:

```
FactVar <- factor(Var, levels=c(1,2,8,9), labels=c("Yes", "No", "Don't Know", "Not Applicable
```

and will include the labels and levels of unused factors.

Comment: Sorry @Greg but I got something different: `Factor w/ 4 levels "Yes","No","Don't Know",..: 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 3 1 2`. Maybe should I add some attributes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different problem, but based on, for example, shadowtalker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952193/7002525), I think the answer is the same: you cannot get the association.

I'm interested in turning a variable into a factor AND keeping the original data. It seems that I have to create a new variable and keep both.

The [Factors help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor) page in R documentation states that

> To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

For example:

```
> v <- c( 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 6 )
> 
> f1 <- factor( x = v, levels = c( 0, 3, 6, 9 ) )
> 
> as.numeric( levels( f1 ) )[f1]
[1] 0 0 3 0 6 6
>
> as.numeric( as.character( f1 ) )
[1] 0 0 3 0 6 6
```

However, if the factor is labelled, neither of the above methods work:

```
> f2 <- factor( x = v, levels = c( 0, 3, 6, 9 ), labels = c( "a", "b", "c", "d" ) )
> 
> as.numeric( levels( f2 ) )[f2]
Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>
> as.numeric( as.character( f2 ) )
Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

This is obvious if we look at what `levels()` and `as.character()` give:

```
> levels( f2 )
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
>
> as.numeric( levels( f2 ) )
Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
[1] NA NA NA NA
>
> as.character( f2 )
[1] "a" "a" "b" "a" "c" "c"
```

If we just use `as.numeric()`, we get the new level values created by `factor()`:

```
> as.numeric( f2 )
[1] 1 1 2 1 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the example:

```
> Var <- c(4,5,4,5,8)
> FactVar <- factor(Var, levels=c(4,5,8,9), labels=c("Yes", "No", "Don't Know", "Not Applicable"))

> FactVar
[1] Yes        No         Yes        No         Don't Know
Levels: Yes No Don't Know Not Applicable
```

we can see *all* of the remaining information that R maintains about `FactVar` using the `unclass()` function:

```
> unclass(FactVar)

[1] 1 2 1 2 3
attr(,"levels")
[1] "Yes"            "No"             "Don't Know"     "Not Applicable"
```

What you can see is that R doesn't retain the original `c(4,5,4,5)` data.  It simply takes the original data, finds the unique "levels" and numbers consecutively starting at 1.  Then it stores the factor as an integer vector of value ranging from 1 to number of levels.  The fact that the original data contained 4's, 5's and 8's is entirely lost and therefore irrecoverable.

In the end, the intended purpose of a factor in R is to create a vector of integers *ranging from 1 to n_levels*, where the integer stands in for a named category.  Most commonly, this is used to code character vectors as numeric categories.

In my opinion, converting integers to factors in something that might only be useful in a small set of circumstances.  All you are doing, really, is remapping the integers (in the example, 4, 5, and 8) to a new set of integers (1, 2, and 3) and then displaying names that are associated with the new set of integers.

So I don't think this is a design limitation.  I think maybe folks are wanting factors to do more than they were intended to do by design.

If you want to maintain the original values and have class names associated with them, perhaps just name the original vector?

```
> Var <- c(4,5,4,5,8)

> hash <- c(Yes = 4, No = 5, `Don't Know` = 8, `Not Applicable` = 9)

> namedVar <- hash[match(Var, hash)]

> namedVar

       Yes         No        Yes         No Don't Know 
         4          5          4          5          8
```

Another solution would be to put both in a data.frame:

```
> Var <- c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,8,1,2)
> data.frame(Var = Var, FactVar = factor(Var, levels=c(1,2,8,9), labels=c("Yes", "No", "Don't Know", "Not Applicable")))
   Var    FactVar
1    1        Yes
2    2         No
3    1        Yes
4    2         No
5    2         No
6    2         No
7    1        Yes
8    8 Don't Know
9    1        Yes
10   2         No
>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand what you mean.
You can specify the labels for the levels of your factors.

```
df$FactVar <- factor(df$FactVar, levels=c(paste0("city", 1:4))) # assuming you go up to 'city4'
```

The point being is that you can specify the levels in any order you want using the `levels` parameter in the function `factor`